# Is there any other style presenting an UIAlertView?

Tags: iphone, uialertview

I saw one app in which the notification/alert view was coming from the top of the iphone screen with gradient black color.

May I have details about alert/notification styles if any?

Comment: Google for 'custom UIAlertViews in iPhone'

Comment: Are you talking about *notifications* or *alert views*?  Those are entirely different things!

Answer (score 1):

you may use this link ... maybe it will help you. one other way is to use UIActionsheet.

http://joris.kluivers.nl/blog/2009/04/23/subclass-uialertview-to-create-a-custom-alert/

Comment: Just now I checked this link :)

Comment: It doesn't work anymore they had changed the subclass hierarchy

Comment: @Andrea tell me wat you want ?? alert or actionsheet?

Comment: That tutorial is old, it doesn't work anymore, Apple has moved the drawing of the background in a uiimageview, checkbox my answer below..just saying that

Answer (score 0):

There's the `UIActionSheet`—but it is raises from the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not. And customize the original UIAlertView is a trick, that acts on subviews hierarchies. you can sub class it and change it's background color overriding the `drawRect:` method and removing the original background with those lines of code

```
- (void)didAddSubview:(UIView *)subview {
if ([subview isMemberOfClass:[UIImageView class]]) {
    [subview removeFromSuperview];
}
}
```

But it is a trick and it could be lost in future release of iOS